# Receiving no response when I do a call using retrofit2

Tags: java, retrofit2

I'm fetching a list of data from a MySQL database using Retrofit2. I want to put all the fetched data into a RecyclerView in android but response isn't successful. I did `Call<Loan>` at first, it returned a response but my adapter is only accepting List Array so I changed it to `Call<List<Loan>>` but now response is unsuccessful. I did a postman request and it returned data, so I don't know where I did wrong.

fetchLoans Method

```
public void fetchLoans(String key){

    final Call<List<Loan>> loanCall = ApiClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .fetchLoans(key);

    loanCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Loan>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Loan>> call, Response<List<Loan>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    List<Loan> loanList = response.body();
                    loanAdapter = new LoanAdapter(context, loanList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(loanAdapter);
                    loanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No loans at the moment" + response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Request failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Loan>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

My API method

```
@GET("Loans/fetch_loan.php?")
Call<List<Loan>> fetchLoans(
        @Query("keyWord") String keyWord);
```

My POJO Class

```
public class Loan {
@SerializedName("ID") private int ID;
@SerializedName("admID") private int admID;
@SerializedName("fullName") private String fullName;
@SerializedName("contactNo") private String contactNo;
@SerializedName("borrowedAmt") private double borrowedAmt;
@SerializedName("borrowedDate") private String borrowedDate;
@SerializedName("interestRate") private String interestRate;
@SerializedName("interest") private double interest;
@SerializedName("paymentType") private String paymentType;
@SerializedName("message") private String message;
@SerializedName("success") private Boolean success;

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public void setAdmID(int admID) {
    this.admID = admID;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public void setBorrowedAmt(double borrowedAmt) {
    this.borrowedAmt = borrowedAmt;
}

public void setBorrowedDate(String borrowedDate) {
    this.borrowedDate = borrowedDate;
}

public void setInterestRate(String interestRate) {
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
}

public void setInterest(double interest) {
    this.interest = interest;
}

public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}
public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public int getAdmID() {
    return admID;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public String getContactNo() {
    return contactNo;
}

public double getBorrowedAmt() {
    return borrowedAmt;
}

public String getBorrowedDate() {
    return borrowedDate;
}

public String getInterestRate() {
    return interestRate;
}

public double getInterest() {
    return interest;
}

public String getPaymentType() {
    return paymentType;
}
```

}

What it returns when I do a request in Postman.

[Fetchloan request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ1c0.png)

Comment: What's the actual response?

Comment: Response is null

Comment: Apologies, should have been more clear. Not talking about the Object Response, talking about the actual server response. You're saying you got it to work with Postman? That structure is important

Comment: Yeah I got it working with postman have a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ1c0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see difference in URL. In your API method it is `Loans/fetch_loan.php?` where in your Postman sceenshot it is `Loans/fetchLoan.php?`.

If it's true, then surely you're not getting success response. Or change your API method URL to `@GET("Loans/fetchLoan.php?")`. (replace **underscore** with uppercase **L**)

And also you don't need to use `?` at end of the URL in API method. Retrofit's `@Query` adds it internally.

It is always good practice to log the error messages instead of just Toasting. Like

```
Log.e("TAG", "Error: ", t);
```

Comment: Yeah I found it out last night! Thank you! :))))